# Delphi file dialog won't handle Sharepoint urls

Tags: delphi, sharepoint

In my Delphi program I can access a Sharepoint folder by using an indy TidHTTP component

```
    MyURL:=MySite+'_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('''+listname+''')/Files';
    IdHTTP.Get(MyURL);
```

But if I want the user to select a file using the familiar Open dialog like this

```
  selectedFile := '';
  dlg := TOpenDialog.Create(nil);
  try
    dlg.InitialDir := MyURL;
    dlg.Filter := 'All files (*.*)|*.*';
    if dlg.Execute(Handle) then
      selectedFile := dlg.FileName;
  finally
    dlg.Free;
  end;
```

Then I get the error:
"You can't open this location using this program. Please try a different location".

Do I have to modify the URL for TOpenDialog to handle it correctly?

Comment: Where did you see that you could assign a URL to [`TOpenDialog.InitialDir`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.Dialogs.TOpenDialog.InitialDir)?

Comment: Olivier - I don't know any other way to specify the location. Documentation on Sharepoint access is difficult to find.

Comment: Sharepoint doesn't work that way.  It's not a filesystem or accessible via the filesystem - it is its own encapsulated platform.  You can [map sharepoint libraries to a network drive](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/map-a-network-drive-to-a-sharepoint-library-751148de-f579-42f9-bc8c-fcd80ccf0f53), however.  Perhaps this is what you're trying to do?

Comment: `TOpenDialog` does not support using URLs for viewing remote content. It only supports local filesystem paths.